# Bootstrap 3 contact form with recaptcha v2

Tags: forms, contacts

I ran into in issue with my contact form on www.baddeleyspourhouselb.com/contact.php and I was hoping someone would be able to tell me what happened to my form. It submits (not with ajax like it should) and does nothing when the file is not commented out. I followed the tutorial on https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-recaptcha. I had it working perfectly for weeks and implemented on another site as well, which is working fine. I have gone back through and looked at it line by line and can’t figure this out for the life of me. Any help or advice would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, everyone. The problem was above my form code, where I had accidentally declared a second #contact-form ID.